# kubernetes cannot ping another service

Tags: kubernetes

DNS resolution looks fine, but I cannot ping my service. What could be the reason?

From another pod in the cluster:

```
$ ping backend
PING backend.default.svc.cluster.local (10.233.14.157) 56(84) bytes of data.


^C
--- backend.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
36 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 35816ms
```

EDIT:

The service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: backend
  name: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - name: api
    protocol: TCP
    port: 10000
  selector:
    app: backend
```

The deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: nha/backend:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: api
          containerPort: 10000
```

I can `curl` my service from the same container:

```
kubectl exec -it backend-7f67c8cbd8-mf894 -- /bin/bash
root@backend-7f67c8cbd8-mf894:/# curl localhost:10000/my-endpoint
{"ok": "true"}
```

It looks like the endpoint on port `10000` does not get exposed though:

```
 kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                                       AGE
backend      <none>                                                          2h
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [kubernetes service IPs not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705432/kubernetes-service-ips-not-reachable)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ping doesn't work with service's cluster IPs like 10.233.14.157, as it is a virtual IP. You should be able to ping a specific pod, but no a service.

Comment: That would make sense - how do I ping one specific pod then?

Comment: Just use `kubectl get pod` to list all pods, and then `kubectl describe pod <YOUR POD NAME>` to see all info about it. There is a field called IP.

Comment: @nha `kubectl get pod -owide -n xxx` and you'll see `IP`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to ping/access a pod *through service*? Isn't that the point of services; that I don't need to get the IP address of individual containers anymore?

Comment: That is true for TCP or UDP traffic, but not for ICMP which is used when you run ping. If you wanna test a connection to a service, use netcat to generate TCP or UDP traffic.

Comment: `Just use kubectl get pod to list all pods, and then kubectl describe pod <YOUR POD NAME> to see all info about it. There is a field called IP`

This is not a good answer.  You'd need to have kubectl installed on all your pods.

Answer (score 15):

You can't ping a service. You can curl it.

Comment: I first tried `curl` and it wasn't working, so I though I would then use `ping` to see if it was reachable.

Comment: You can't ping a service. You can use `curl` or `wget`. For example `wget -O- 10.152.183.210:80` . I prefer `wget` because it is usually available in small images such as `busybox`