# Can't reach out a ClusterIP service from within a pod in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, networking, deployment, cluster-computing

I have made a nginx deployment which will be tagged by a ClusterIP service via a selector. Then I entered a new pod that is not related to that deployment nor service. And from within that pod I try to ping the i.p of the ClusterIP service hoping it would reach the nginx deploy, but it's not receiving the ping response.

The nginx deployment I made was with this manifest.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Then, the service I created was with this manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: basicping-service
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

I made sure the service got created by running `kubectl get svc` and it did, the i.p is `10.98.91.185`

And then I created a new pod completely unrelated to this deployment&Service.

`kubectl run -it --rm --image=ubuntu  bash`

From within it, I pinged a sandbox server called `pingtest.net` just to see it was able to send requests and receive response. And it did

So finally, I tried pinging the `basicping-service` created previously by trying to ping the i.p of the service, I did this by running `ping 10.98.91.185`

And here is the problem. It does sends pings but doesn't receives the responses back, even after several minutes.

It was my understanding that the ping should have received a response. But is my understanding of services incorrect ? Or it should have worked but there is an error?

Just for more documentation, the my-nginx deployment is running, and the pod as well. And there seems to be nothing wrong with the nginx running in it. I checked this by running the `kubectl describe` of the deploy & pod, and also by checking the pod's logs, it's running nginx correctly apparently. Also, after running `kubectl describe svc basicping-service` it does shows the nginx pod's i.p address with port 80 as the endpoint

Comment: You should be able to ping a specific pod, but no a service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852542/kubernetes-cannot-ping-another-service

Comment: ping(1) sends packets using the very-low-level ICMP protocol, but Nginx serves HTTP which uses the TCP protocol instead.  Can you `curl` or `wget` the Pod via the Service?

Comment: Yes I can crul and wget, I get that was the problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ping doesn't work with a service's cluster IP, as it is a virtual IP.
You should be able to ping a specific pod, but not a service.

ping sends packets using the very-low-level ICMP protocol, but Nginx serves HTTP which uses the TCP protocol instead.