# viewing log of exited pod

Tags: coreos, rkt

I'm trying to install kubernetes on my CoreOS cluster but it's not that relevant to my question.

I'm on Container Linux by CoreOS alpha (1339.0.0) with rkt:

```
rkt Version: 1.25.0
appc Version: 0.8.10
Go Version: go1.7.3
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Features: -TPM +SDJOURNAL
```

I have a specific pod that keeps exiting.

for example, `rkt list --full` shows me:

```
914c4f3f-6e3a-44c2-a111-bfc91ceb411a    kubedns         gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64:1.9              sha512-c7b7c9c4393b exited      2017-03-13 13:34:10.306 +0000 UTC   2017-03-13 13:34:11.246 +0000 UTC
```

it's `exited` and i want see the pod's logs.

now... according to https://github.com/coreos/rkt/blob/master/Documentation/commands.md I should the machinectl Id which i can't find, so it tells me to append `rkt-` to the uuid string.

so I tried every combination I could think of:

```
# journalctl -m _MACHINE_ID=914c4f3f-6e3a-44c2-a111-bfc91ceb411a
-- No entries --
# journalctl -M rkt-914c4f3f-6e3a-44c2-a111-bfc91ceb411a
Failed to open root directory: No machine 'rkt-914c4f3f-6e3a-44c2-a111-bfc91ceb411a' known
# journalctl -u rkt-914c4f3f-6e3a-44c2-a111-bfc91ceb411a
-- No entries --
```

so.. what an I do to see the logs output of an exited pod? :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice that rkt-gc.timer keeps garbage collecting my old pods cause I was running out of space quickly. once I disabled and stopped rkt-gc.timer in my cloud-config, I was able to view the logs using `journalctl -m _MACHINE_ID=UID_WITHOUT_-`

just removed the `-` from the UID output of `rkt list --full`.